# Do these 2 mathematical expressions both refer to the same thing?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

(1)$ (\forall a \in S)(\exists e \in S) $
(2)$(\exists e \in S)(\forall a \in S)$

Are  $(1)\equiv(2) $ or the order in which I write them has some different meaning ?
Basically, I have been told that (1) and (2) are not the same mathematical expressions ... Could someone please explain why aren't they the same ?

Comment: Have you tried replacing the mathematical statements with maybe an english example/interpretation?

Comment: Yes I did, thats why it doesn't make any logical sense to me why these 2 aren't the same... For example say a= men and e= woman .. You will find out that its exactly the same, but mathematically it should not ..

Comment: Try adding a proposition to the end Perhaps add "$L(a,e)$" which might be interpreted as "$a$ loves $e$". Then using your interpretation of men and women, what does it translate to?

Comment: (1): For every natural number $a$ there exists a natural number $e$ such that $a\lt e$. (2): There exists a natural number $e$ such that, for every natural number $a$, $a\lt e$. Obviously (1) is true and (2) is false.

Comment: Perhaps part of the confusion is that neither (1) nor (2) is a statement, just the beginning of one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everyone is someone's child, but nobody is everyone's parent.

In symbols: taking "$C(a, b)$" to mean "$a$ is $b$'s child," we have $\forall x\exists y C(x, y)$ but $\neg \exists y\forall x C(x, y)$.

"$\exists x\forall y\varphi(x, y)$" says that not only does every $y$ have an $x$ such that $\varphi(x, y)$ holds, but there is one *single* $x$ which works for every $y$. This is in general a much stronger claim.

Another example worth considering is that the statement "There is no largest number" can be written in two natural ways: "For all $x$ there is some $y$ such that $x<y$" and "NOT(there is some $y$ such that for all $x$, $x<y$)." In this example, not only are "$\forall x\exists y$" and "$\exists y\forall x$" not equivalent, they're actually direct opposites!

Answer (score 1):

$\forall$ means "for all" but sometimes more cleanly translates as "for any" or "for every."

$\exists$ means "there exists" but might be interpreted as "we can find."

For any point, $a,$ on the number line, there is a point $e$ on the number line that is greater than $a.$

Clearly true.

There exists a point on the number line $e,$ for every point $a$ on the number line $a$ is greater than $e.$

This implies that $e$ is the smallest point.  Or that there is a least element which might be true in $\mathbb N$ but is not true in $\mathbb Z$ or $\mathbb R$